# Output URLS to json

Tags: cakephp, json

I want to generate web URLs to files uploaded by users, and serialize them.
In the controller I can do something like:

```
$myURL = Router::url('/', TRUE) . 'files' . DS . $relationName . DS . 'attachment' . DS . $attachmentData['dir'] . $attachmentData['attachment'];
```

But if the filename has spaces, it will not be escaped.

I know I can use the html helper in the view, but this means I will not be able to use the serialize magic from the controller.Also I don't want to break cake by using the HTML helper in the controller, or model.

I's there a way to create web URLs (http://example.c.../someimage.jpg) to files in webroot from the controller?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following tests variables passed in `serialize`:

```
$test = 'http://my.url.com/test.jpg';
$test1 = 'http://my.url.com/test file.jpg';
$test2 = urlencode('http://my.url.com/test file.jpg');
```

And the result is:

```
"test": "http:\/\/my.url.com\/test.jpg",
"test1": "http:\/\/my.url.com\/test file.jpg",
"test2": "http%3A%2F%2Fmy.url.com%2Ftest+file.jpg"
```

So I don't see any problem, urls are properly JSON encoded in `test` and `test1` and `test2` is already urlencoded from PHP so it is passed as is.

Comment: But after the JSON unparsing, only the first test will be a valid URL for making a request to it. (correct me if wrong)

Comment: All tests yield the original contents of the variable, including a filename *with* a space in 2 and 3. Obviously for the third you will need urldecoding. If you have a filename "test file.jpg" then you will be able to access it. If this doesn't answer your question then you need to be more specific as to what the problem is.

Comment: The problem is that not every program adds percent escapes (i.e. change the spaces for '%20') automatically (most browsers do) and the JSON should be compatible with programs that doesn't do that.